# Kendoui ComboBox prefetch & preselect item with server filtering

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-combobox

I need to see an example of a kendoui Combobox (either MVC or client side code) preselecting an item (not only value) from datasource.The datasource has server filtering enabled.The issue i am facing is that when i bind my mvc combobox to a model property (e.g. UserID), only the value (which is the user ID) is bound and not the Name which is the textfiled.When clicking on the combobox arrow, the selected item is not poping up,meaning that there is no selected item and only the widget element (e.g. input) value is set.Most of the examples i have seen shows how to set the selected value or text, but does not address the issue of the absence of a selected item.Here is my code:

```
@Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.UserID).DataValueField("ID").DataTextField("Name").Filter(FilterType.Contains).MinLength(3).DataSource(source =>
                        {
                            source.Custom().Type("aspnetmvc-ajax").Transport(transport => transport.Read(read =>
                            {
                                read.Action("GetAllUsers", "User");
                            })).ServerFiltering(true).ServerPaging(true).PageSize(50);
                        }).AutoBind(false)
```

The autoBind is false so that the combobox does not hit the data service with an empty filter which would return a useless 50 records.Instead of this, the desired behaviour is that the combobox datasource should send the filter (e.g: UserID=50) by default and should return the record and add the item to the combobox.I have found a workround for this issue but do not know if this the easiest way to do it:

```
combobox.dataSource.filter({ field: 'UserID', operator: 'eq', value: 50 });
```

If I call the above code, the item is preselected, and my combobox would have only one item which is what i wanted, but the next time i try to change the selected item by typing another user name, the filter would fail because the earlier filter is still attached to the datasource.I solved this by calling:

```
combobox.dataSource.filter().filters.shift()
```

Any help for finding a shortcut will be appreciated.

Comment: If those APIs (the filter ones) are working, then you're good. Both of those are valid and supported APIs.

Comment: Thanks Burke.I feel that there (is/should be) a shortcut for setting the selected item (not only the value) through a builtin function which once called, should send the correct filter to the server and then sets the selected item to the first returned record.The value set method should check if server filtering is true and calls this function to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

There's documentation for this [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/dropdownlist/how-to/selection/preselect-items). The example below is taken from the page and based on DropDownList which is applicable to ComboBox too.

```
<div id="example">
    <div class="demo-section k-header">
      <h4>View Order Details</h4>
      <p>
        <label for="categories">Categories:</label><input id="categories" style="width: 270px" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="products">Products:</label><input id="products" disabled="disabled" style="width: 270px" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="orders">Orders:</label><input id="orders" disabled="disabled" style="width: 270px" />
      </p>

      <button class="k-button" id="get">View Order</button>
    </div>

    <style scoped>
      .demo-section {
        width: 400px;
      }
      .demo-section p {
        margin-top: 1em;
      }
      .demo-section label {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        text-align: right;
      }
      .demo-section .k-button {
        margin: 1em 0 0 105px;
      }
      .k-readonly
      {
        color: gray;
      }
    </style>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var categories = $("#categories").kendoDropDownList({
          optionLabel: "Select category...",
          dataTextField: "CategoryName",
          dataValueField: "CategoryID",
          dataSource: {
            type: "odata",
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
              read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Categories"
            }
          },
          dataBound: function() {
            this.search("Grains/Cereals");
            this.select(this.selectedIndex);
          }
        }).data("kendoDropDownList");

        var products = $("#products").kendoDropDownList({
          autoBind: false,
          cascadeFrom: "categories",
          optionLabel: "Select product...",
          dataTextField: "ProductName",
          dataValueField: "ProductID",
          dataSource: {
            type: "odata",
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
              read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Products"
            }
          },
          dataBound: function() {
            this.search("Gnocchi di nonna Alice");
            this.select(this.selectedIndex);
          }
        }).data("kendoDropDownList");

        var orders = $("#orders").kendoDropDownList({
          autoBind: false,
          cascadeFrom: "products",
          optionLabel: "Select order...",
          dataTextField: "Order.ShipCity",
          dataValueField: "OrderID",
          dataSource: {
            type: "odata",
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
              read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Order_Details?$expand=Order"
            }
          },
          dataBound: function() {
            this.search("Albuquerque");
          }
        }).data("kendoDropDownList");
      });

    </script>
  </div>
```